# Python3 Twisted Reverse Proxy Redirecting Incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted

I am trying to make a reverse proxy with Twisted. However, I get some unexpected behaviour when I try adding a child resource.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web import proxy, server

site1 = proxy.ReverseProxyResource('youtube.com', 80, b'')
site2 = proxy.ReverseProxyResource('yahoo.com', 80, b'')

root = Resource()
root.putChild(b"app1", site1)
root.putChild(b"app2", site2)

reactor.listenTCP(8090, Site(root))
reactor.run()
```

From my understanding, the program should redirect "127.0.0.1/app1:8090" to youtube.com. However, it is simply redirecting to "https://127.0.0.1/app1:8090", which then gives an "Unable to connect" error in my browser.

The problem persists even if I convert site1 to a Site, through:

`site1 = Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('youtube.com', 80, b''))`

Replacing b'' by b'/' also does not solve the issue.
I suspect the issue may be something like the browser cannot even find the resource in the first place - which is why it tries to find the https version but still fails. For example, trying to connect to 192.168.1.132 (nothing there) in my browser redirects to https://192... before telling me there's a problem.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Youtube, as well as most sites, don't support HTTP anymore, only HTTPS on port 443. Youtube is trying to redirect to it's secured version. You can't proxy a secure connection though without messing with certificates.

Comment: @mousetail I see, however, replacing "youtube.com" with "192.168.1.100" (local website) gives the same behaviour. And regardless, if I don't use a child and say to proxy to youtube on that port, it will just redirect me to https://youtube.com. Does it maybe have something to do with the fact the browser can't even get to the reverse proxy since that seems like typical "I just can't find it" behaviour.

Comment: Not sure if that is a typo or not but in your browser you should try to connect to `127.0.0.1:8090/app1` and not `127.0.0.1/app1:8090` (See where the port is in the url)

Comment: @Paul thank you! It was not a typo. It works well now for youtube and yahoo. However, I get "Could not connect" when trying to proxy to "192.168.1.100/admin". Just "192.168.1.100" gives Bad Request error. I know it's out of the scope of the question, but any idea?

Comment: Without knowing what is your local app and your updated code it's complicated to help ! Maybe try to search a bit more and open a new question if you can't find the problem !

Comment: No problem ! I added my comment as an answer so you can mark the post as answered ! Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is a typo or not but in your browser you should try to connect to `127.0.0.1:8090/app1` and not `127.0.0.1/app1:8090` (See where the port is in the url)